# Many to many relationship with EF code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I'm starting out the development of an Asp.NET MVC5 app with EF code first model which is supposed to have Members who know Languages and then Languages link back to members who know that language so it's a many-to-many kind of relationship.

```
public class Member 
{
  ...
  public List<Language> Languages { set; get; }

}

public class Language
{
  public in Id {get;set;}
  public string shortName {set;get;}
  public HashSet<Member> mastersOf { get;set; }
}
```

Q1. Is this a viable approach? I'm new to EF code first and this is the first idea after some tutorial googling. Later on, there will be search for members with a specific language only.

Q2. How to make the Language "immutable" so that there is only one row for each language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be

```
public class Member 
{
   ...
   public virtual ICollection<Language> Languages { set; get; }

}

public class Language
{
   public in Id {get;set;}
   public string shortName {set;get;}
   public virtual ICollection<Member> MastersOf { get;set; }
}
```

An even better approach would be to go for a mapping table, to map members and languages. This way you would have a table with one entry for every member and you would have a table with one entry for every language. The 3rd mapping table would have all the combinations.

```
public class Member 
{
   ...
   public virtual ICollection<MemberLanguage> Languages { set; get; }

}

public class Language
{
   public in Id {get;set;}
   public string shortName {set;get;}
   public virtual ICollection<MemberLanguage> MastersOf { get;set; }
}

public class MemberLanguage
{
   public int MemberId {get; set;} 
   public int LanguageId {get; set;}
   public virtual Member Member { set; get; }  //linked to memberid by convention
   public virtual Language Language { set; get; } //linked to languageid by convention
}
```

Comment: How is the latter better approach?

Comment: Well I prefer base tables (of base objects) to have 1 unique row per object. In the latter approach there would be only 1 entry for each member and only 1 entry for each language. 

For me this is more logic to perform statistics, automations, operations, etc... 

The intermediate table "MemberLanguage" will contain all the connections between those 2 base tables. In this way you can also easiliy manage the connections separately, and create easy statistics on it.

In your approach each of the 2 tables will have multiple rows for 1 member. (depending on how many language he knows)

Comment: As a side note. It is even possible to do search queries on only the intermediate table MemberLanguage (as both the MemberId en LanguageId are indexed). By retrieving all the 'MemberLanguage' objects for one members or for one language you can easily iterate these 'MemberLanguage' objects to access the Member and/or Language base object.

Answer (score 0):

Well imho there are some missing things :

- virtual for the navigation properties (usefull for proxy generation)
- some consistency for the type of enumerable navigation properties, personnally I use ICollection
- a t after the in for the Id property of the Language class
- ...

  public class Member 
  {
      ...
      public virtual ICollection Languages { set; get; }

  }

  public class Language
  {
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public string shortName {set;get;}
      public virtual ICollection mastersOf { get;set; }
  }

R1: this is a viable approach, but you will need some configuration code

R2: not sure to understand so my answer is the following : always (when possible) use context attached entities when setting a navigation property.